# Real time html editor for download

Tags: php, html, download, editor, real-time

I like solution in this post [Real-Time Html editor with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409389/real-time-html-editor-with-javascript) or editor on [this site](https://htmledit.squarefree.com/). Just simple solution without extra functionalities.

How to edit the code to add SAVE/LOAD option? Is there somethin like "downloadable little CMS" to play with HTML/CSS? **I want upload it to my hosting, easy access from home/phone/work**, I do not want use online services like codepen or Liveweave.

thanks!

EDIT: Due to comments, I will clarify my question. I have some hosting, mySite.com. There is folder with this magic editor, mySite.com/xxx where i have some sample images and some basic css etc.. Im learning html/css, so I developing some basic html temapltes. HTML editor I linked is just fine. Only I need add 3 buttons, NEW/OPEN/SAVE which make new html file/can open it in live editor/and save it. AND I WANT HAVE THIS EASY SOLUTION ON MY OWN HOSTING.

Comment: You could just edit files and run them on your local machine with a split screen, with your editor on one side and a browser on the right, as most browsers can render html/css files

Comment: do you mean codepen?

Comment: @CoderTang "I want upload it to my hosting, easy access from home/phone/work" - mean i dont want to run this on my local machine...

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas "I do not want use online services like codepen or Liveweave" - mean I dont want use codepan.. :/

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I will tell you why. I have website mySite.com, its much easier have there hidden folder and write mySite.com/xxx into adress bar than log in any web service every time I open it at work (everytime i close broswer at work, it clear cache+cookies+logins). Plus metro in Prague does not have mobile signal at all places. If you go to work 40 mins this way, you can sync your project to your phone and spend this time on your project (html template) offline...

Comment: @spidyCZZ like this help can help you? https://reactgo.com/build-your-own-html-editor/

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas It can be next simple solution, but again without save/load function.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas It can be next simple solution, but again without save/load function. I edit this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409389/real-time-html-editor-with-javascript , so i can load anyFile.html into textarea with php "fopen" and "fread" .. Okay.. Now i need add button to save content from textarea to anyFile.html (overwrite it when im done with changes). Im not sure, look like it can not be done only with php... and Im lost in javascript.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm done. Here is my final solution.

- real-time html editor
- Load/save buttons
- automatically load files from /projects/ folder into dropdown list
- you can upload files to make new project
- no need to modify anything, you can just use it.

Index.php

```
<?php
$fileName = $_POST['project']?? 'index.html';
$fileContent = fopen("./projects/" . $fileName, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    file_put_contents("./projects/" . $fileName, $_POST["text"]);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="cs"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style> 
.error {background-color:red; color:white;}
.dib {display:inline-block;}
</style>
</head><body>

<?php 
echo "<form class='dib' method='POST'><select name='project'>";
$path    = './projects/';
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
foreach($files as $file){
  echo "<option" . (($fileName == $file)?' selected':'') . ">" . $file . "</option>";
} 
echo "</select> <input type='submit' value='Load!'></form>";
?>

<input type='submit' form='content' value='Save!'> 

    <form class="dib" style="float:right;" action="fileUploadScript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload a File:
        <input type="file" name="the_file" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload">
    </form>

<p style='margin:auto; text-align:center; width:20%; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight: bold;'><?php echo $fileName?></p>

<br>
<form id="content" method="POST">
<textarea name="text" rows="40" id="pure" style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;" wrap="off">
<?php echo fread($fileContent,filesize("./projects/" . $fileName)); ?> 
</textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="project" value="<?php echo $fileName; ?>">
</form>
<hr>
<div id="compiled"></div>
</body>
</html>

 <?php
fclose($fileContent);
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var h = document.getElementById("pure");
var compiled = document.getElementById("compiled");
h.onkeyup = function() {
  compiled.innerHTML = h.value;
  pure.classList.toggle("error",
    compiled.innerHTML !== h.value); 
};
h.onkeyup();
</script>
```

fileUploadScript.php

```
<?php
    $currentDirectory = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = "/projects/";

    $errors = []; // Store errors here

    $fileExtensionsAllowed = ['jpeg','jpg','txt','bmp','html','htm','rar','zip','7z','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','ppt','pptx','pdf','pptm','png','gif']; // These will be the only file extensions allowed 

    $fileNamee = $_FILES['the_file']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['the_file']['type'];
    $tmp = explode('.',$fileNamee);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($tmp));

    $uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileNamee); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensionsAllowed)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
      }

      if ($fileSize > 4000000) {
        $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (4MB)";
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileNamee) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
          echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
      } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
      }

    }
?>
```

**After you save these two files, dont forget make new folder named "projects" and default file called "index.html" in this folder..**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$fileName = "page.html";
$fileContent = fopen($fileName, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    file_put_contents($fileName, $_POST["text"]);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="cs"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style> 
.error {background-color: red; color: white;}
</style>

</head><body>

<form method="POST">
<textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="20" id="pure">
<?php echo fread($fileContent,filesize($fileName)); ?> 
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<hr>
<div id="compiled"></div>
</body>
</html>

 <?php
fclose($fileContent);
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var h = document.getElementById("pure");
var compiled = document.getElementById("compiled");
h.onkeyup = function() {
  compiled.innerHTML = h.value;
  pure.classList.toggle("error",
    compiled.innerHTML !== h.value); 
};
h.onkeyup();
</script>
```

Its my actual work, real-time html editor from link in my question. File "page.html" must exist.

Added func. to load content from "page.html" file into textarea when page loads..

Added button to save textarea content to "page.html" when done..

Probably not perfect code, and for multiple projects must copy into diferent folders and load one by one :( no popup or form to choose diferent filename easily.. but for now it fits my requirements. I can learn/try/work on html template from home/work/mobile on my own hosting without login into third party service.